# Screen is stuck on black after starting

Tags: boot

Begining of the boot the screen remain stuck on black screen. How will I solve this problem?

Comment: Please give us some information to go on - what’s your hardware, which version of Ubuntu, any recent system changes that might have caused this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using a VM then I highly recommend you to use ram more than 1GB i.e, you can use 1.5GB atleast because as it is a VM you have allocate more RAM than normally minimum required amount.
- If you are using ubuntu as a dualboot or as a primary os then, are you able to see grub?

Comment: It started after I tried to install SCM package. After that I was unable to log in. It was showing something like access needed. I rebooted it. Now I can't get any log in screen. I am only able to go tty1.  Nothing  I can do like update, reinstall ubuntu-desktop. Nothing works. It only shows failed to fetch.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide some screenshot.

Comment: I can't upload picture. It is not uploading. Can I do it any other medium?

Comment: I get these lines

/dev/sda5: recovering journal

/dev/sda5: clean, 421830/30498816 files, 10247137/121964800 blocks

I TIME 1 Timed out waiting for device /deu/disk/by-uuid [DEPEND] Dependency failed for File Systen Check on /dev/disk/by-unid-AE45-1673.

AE45-1673.

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi. [DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.

[FAILED] Failed to start Load Appfarmor profiles.

-

Comment: And later on
 Ubuntu 28.84.3 LTS Suraj-Acer-one-14-2422 ttyl

Suraj-Acer-one-14-2422 login:

Comment: Try uploading to imgur using this [link](https://imgur.com/upload).

Comment: It says we can not find that page